# Что происходит в строке кода const ProbabilityTable a = *(ProbabilityTable*)elem1?

Tags: c++, указатели, struct, const, qsort

Что происходит в строке кода

```
const ProbabilityTable a = *(ProbabilityTable*)elem1
```

в следующей функции:

```
struct ProbabilityTable { 
        unsigned char symb;
        double prob;    };

static int ProbabTableComp(const void *elem1, const void *elem2){ // метод сравнения для qsort  
   const ProbabilityTable a = *(ProbabilityTable*)elem1;
   const ProbabilityTable b = *(ProbabilityTable*)elem2;
   if (a.prob < b.prob)         
      return 1;     
   else if (a.prob > b.prob)        
      return -1;    
   else         
      return 0; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const ProbabilityTable a = *(ProbabilityTable*)elem1;
```

В `elem1` находится адрес некоторого места в памяти, которое мы хотим, рассматривая его как переменную типа `ProbabilityTable`, инициализировать ею константу `a`.

Поскольку у нас есть только адрес, выполняя приведение `(ProbabilityTable*)elem1`, мы получаем указатель на `ProbabilityTable`. Чтобы получить само значение, необходимо этот указатель разыменовать с помощью оператора `*`, что и делается в рассматриваемой строке. Ну, а дальше это значение копируется в `a`...

Кстати, я бы не копировал эти значения, а сравнение выполнял, обращаясь непосредственно к местам в памяти. Если структуры большие, копирование может повлиять на производительность...